# finitely generated submodules are flat

Tags: modules, flatness

Assume that all the finitely generated submodules of $M$ are flat, then why is $M$ also flat?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because $M$ is the direct limit of its finitely generated submodules, and a direct limit of flat modules  is flat.